# Getting CommandNotFoundException when trying to run a test case for the first time in Laravel Unit Test

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, phpunit, laravel-artisan

This happens only the first time when I run the test case with a new name.

Eg:
Test case = `it_can_create_a_new_user`

inside the test case it calls `$this->artisan('myapp:create-new-user');`

- When I run this the 1st time it says `Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException: The command "myapp:create-new-user" does not exist.`
- When I run the same test case for the 2nd time it works.

But, if I change the name into `it_can_create_a_new_user_`, It fails with the same error.

So I dig into the Laravel to check how it loads commands and found this in [Kernel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php#L226) class at line 226. It returns `false` in `realpath(app_path())` when the test case runs the 1st time, but not for the 2nd time it returns the *realpath*.

**Note**: I have moved the `app` directory into the `src` folder and changed the `composer.json` as well.

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "src/app/",
  }
},
```

Comment: Why did you move the path ? And can you share your test please ?

Comment: I moved app directory into src is because I just needed to follow DDD in my project.
It is just a simple test, I wrote a command to create new User. Eg: User::create().

Inside of the test `$this->artisan('myapp:create-new-user');` and assert that new user is being created.

Comment: Are you extending `Tests\TestCase` or `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` ?

Comment: Extends to Tests\TestCase

Comment: I am using laravel 7 with php 7.4

Comment: I am not sure then, if your problem is in [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/a36f02c4f2c5617bfe355709ca1955884b11e2d3/bootstrap/app.php#L14-L16). Could you check what `app()->basePath()` returns ? I think the main issue is because you moved `app` folder, but I have never done this so I am not 100% sure what is in the core that could be messing with.